# How to estimate/determine surface normals and tangent planes at points of a depth image (point cloud)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, surfaces, plane-curves

I have depth image, that I've generated using 3D CAD data. This depth image can also be taken from a depth imaging sensor such as Kinect or a stereo camera. So basically it is depth map of points visible in the imaging view. In other words it is segmented point cloud of an object from a certain view.

I would like to determine (estimating will also do) the surface normals of each point, then find tangent plane of that point.

How can I do this? I've did some research and find some techniques but didn't understand them well (I could not implement it). More importantly how can I do this in Matlab? I've couldn't manage to do this using `surfnorm` command. AFAIK it need single surface, and I have partial surfaces in my depth image.

This is an example depth image.

[image]

**[EDIT]**

What I want to do is, after I get the surface normal at each point I will create tangent planes at those points. Then use those tangent planes to decide if that point is coming from a flat region or not by taking the sum of distances of neighbor points to the tangent plane.

**[EDIT]**

Comment: Not really familiar with the kinds of data/structures you have here. Should this be interpreted merely as a collection of points, such that the sensor says, "At $x$ and $y$, the depth reached before we hit something is $z$?"  Or does the map have some notion of how points are connected together?

Comment: You can think the image as a point cloud. Such that there are no points in the black parts. `x` and `y` values are image co-ordinates and `z` values are the pixel values.